# Strange position:absolute behaviour on Mac webkit browsers

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to position a check-mark next to a menu item by doing the following:

```
#userInfo div.dropDownContent p span
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

A span inside a paragraph is absolutely positioned in order to preserve the centering of the menu item's text, otherwise the check-mark is centered along with the text and it makes it look bad.

As you can see in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6L8AA/4/), the check-mark looks ok in your average Windows browser, but Safari on Mac and iPad (perhaps even Chrome on Mac) shows the check-mark outside the menu, and there's nothing I can do to make it move even a pixel.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is it a webkit bug? Thanks.

Comment: Looks okay to me, Chrome 22.0.1229.79/Mac.

Comment: I think it's just Safari then. Chrome does show this behavior, but only on iPad, since it's pretty much just a repackaged Safari.

Comment: Yeah, I see that in Safari. See answer below.

Comment: Can you even give `inline` elements a position?

Comment: @iambriansreed I'm not sure, I thought that maybe the glitch was caused by invalid HTML or CSS. Setting display: block to the inline elements doesn't help though.

Comment: @JayPea Consider it's parent element's position. Setting that to relative should help in positioning the child element(s).

Answer (score 0):

I do see that odd behavior in Safari, and I really can't explain why it's in that browser only.

That being said, [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6L8AA/5/) should show you what worked for me.

Basically, instead of positioning the span absolutely, I used relative positioning and set it to left -20px like so:

```
#userInfo div.dropDownContent p span
{
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this affects the centering of the menu item, which is what I was trying to avoid. I'll see if I can do something to the text itself in order to compensate for the check-mark's width.